# Undefined symbols error when using a header file

Tags: c, linker-errors, undefined-reference, undefined-symbol

I'm getting the following error and can't for the life of me figure out what I'm doing wrong.

```
$ gcc main.c -o main

Undefined symbols:
  "_wtf", referenced from:
      _main in ccu2Qr2V.o
ld: symbol(s) not found
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

**main.c:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "wtf.h"

main(){
    wtf();
}
```

**wtf.h:**

```
void wtf();
```

**wtf.c:**

```
void wtf(){
    printf("I never see the light of day.");
}
```

Now, if I include the entire function in the header file instead of just the signature, it complies fine so I know wtf.h is being included. Why doesn't the compiler see wtf.c? Or am I missing something?

Regards.

Comment: You never told the compiler to compile wtf.c. That's why.

Comment: Yeah, I come from the land of magic and unicorns so I just assumed that having the implementation named the same as the header would allow the compiler to find both.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You need to link `wtf` with your `main`. Easiest way to compile it together - `gcc` will link 'em for you, like this:

```
gcc main.c wtf.c -o main
```

Longer way (separate compilation of `wtf`):

```
gcc -c wtf.c
gcc main.c wtf.o -o main
```

Even longer (separate compilation and linking)

```
gcc -c wtf.c
gcc -c main.c
gcc main.o wtf.o -o main
```

Instead of last `gcc` call you can run `ld` directly with the same effect.

Comment: So what's stopping me from just doing the following?

#include <stdio.h>
#include "wtf.h"
#include "wtf.c"

It feels unpleasant but so does the idea of having to include an argument for every implementation when I run gcc.

Comment: @j33r: Presumably nothing is stopping _you_. _We_, who we need to earn money writing C++ code for a living, however, have our fellow-workers to stop us doing so, in order to protect their sanity. (And if you really didn't know: One of the key features of C is _separate compilation_. Among other things it allows us to deal with the insanely compile-times the preprocessor file inclusion comes with. And then there's also information hiding, encapsulation and other nice - and, unfortunately, often underrated - principles.)

Comment: @j33r: At the point where your program has more than one `.c` file, it's time to write a simple `Makefile` to build it.

Answer (score 4):

You are missing the fact that merely including a header doesn't tell the compiler anything about where the actual implementation (the definitions) of the things *declared* in the header are.

They could be in a C file next to the one doing the include, they could come from a pre-compiled static link library, or a dynamic library loaded by the system linker when reading your executable, or they could come at run-time user programmer-controlled explicit dynamic loading (the `dlopen()` family of function in Linux, for instance).

C is not like Java, there is no implicit rule that just because a C file includes a certain header, the compiler should also do something to "magically" find the implementation of the things declared in the header. You need to tell it.

Comment: You're exactly right. I was assuming that as long as the header file and the implementation were named the same that the compiler would find both when I included the header.

Comment: This explanation for *why separate compilation is a feature* is quite useful. Thanks.